# DNN An Error Has Occurred

Tags: dotnetnuke

Is there a way to get details about this error? I turned off custom errors:

[image]

It looks like I am missing a skin file. How do I get it back? I used the one from the default install of DNN 6.2.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could look at your DotNetNuke log4net config settings and check where you are logging errors. The default location is **{DotNetNuke_Root_Folder}/Portals/_default/Logs/**.

The log level by default is set on error so you can change that to **"Debug"** if you want by changing the  element in the following config file **{DotNetNuke_Root_Folder}/DotNetNuke.log4net.config**

You can copy the skin's folder in your DotNetNuke installation zip file to your installed DotNetNuke website. Path to skins **(DotNetNuke_Community_07.00.05_Install.zip\Portals_default\Skins)**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. I was missing this file: DotNetNuke.Modules.Html

Answer (score 3):

You can get all error detail from LogViewer module of DotNetNuke

Login as administrators then go to **Admin-Event Viewer** , here you can find the details about error.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error also; on a local instance.  After installing a DNN Template via the .visx file, IIS had set up a virtual directory for the desktopmodules folder.  Removing the virtual directory cleared this right up in my case.  Took a long time to troubleshoot, so hopefully this helps someone avoid the wild goose chase.