# DNN: An error has occurred an error has occurred

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am getting the same error mentioned in this post ([DNN An Error Has Occurred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936618/dnn-an-error-has-occurred))
This site is hosted on GoDaddy, and their tech support has not been very helpful so far.

Below is the latest entry from the SQL eventlog, which I can make little sense out of.  If anyone an help me decipher it and have any suggestions, I would be extremely grateful!

---

AssemblyVersion6.1.5PortalID0PortalNameMessiah By The MountainUserID-1UserNameActiveTabID55ActiveTabNameHomeRawURL/mbtm/default.aspxAbsoluteURL/mbtm/default.aspxAbsoluteURLReferrerUserAgentMozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)DefaultDataProviderDotNetNuke.Data.SqlDataProvider, DotNetNuke.SqlDataProviderExceptionGUIDc895efa1-4032-4fa8-991f-d50471307893InnerExceptiond:\hosting\5593428\html\mbtm\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx(51): error CS0433: The type 'ASP.admin_controlpanel_addpage_ascx' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_ukwttza0.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_7boienjh.dll'FileNameFileLineNumber0FileColumnNumber0MethodSystem.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFileStackTraceMessageDotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.PageLoadException: d:\hosting\5593428\html\mbtm\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx(51): error CS0433: The type 'ASP.admin_controlpanel_addpage_ascx' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_ukwttza0.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_7boienjh.dll' ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException: d:\hosting\5593428\html\mbtm\admin\ControlPanel\RibbonBar.ascx(51): error CS0433: The type 'ASP.admin_controlpanel_addpage_ascx' exists in both 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_ukwttza0.dll' and 'c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\mbtm\98d5dbb8\31e1af1b\App_Web_7boienjh.dll' at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(String virtualPath) at DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc) at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.InjectControlPanel() at DotNetNuke.UI.Skins.Skin.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index) at System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(Control child) at DotNetNuke.Framework.DefaultPage.OnInit(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer) at System.Web.UI

Comment: One word of advice, get away from goDaddy. I've heard lots of horror stories from people who use them for DNN. Do yourself a favor and a get a decent DNN host like PowerDNN. I use them and they are the best. A little pricier than GoDaddy but you get what you pay for.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a bit more specific? In which module do you get this error?

I see framework 2.0 in the error which version of DNN are you using? since DNN 5.3 you need framework 3.5

[DNN Installation prerequisites](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/DotNetNuke-Installation-Prerequisites-work-in-progress)

Comment: Actually it is 5.2 that requires .NET 3.5, earlier versions are fine on 2.0

Comment: I have no doubt @ChrisHammond that it is version 5.2 but i was still wondering. On the DNN website it says 5.3. But with you background i can assume it is 5.2 I was wrong!